# why there are hard returns when I merge two files using paste process

Tags: linux, paste

To merge two files below each has 4 lines in 1 column,

> file1
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>
> file2
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8

I use the code "paste file1 file2 > file3"

the expected result is below with tab-delimited speratation

> file3
>   1 5
>   2 6
>   3 7
>   4 8

but gotten file is

```
file3

1

    5

2

    6

3

    7

4

    8
```

How do I handle this problem?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: In fact, two data I used contain very many columns because it is genetic SNP data. Sorry for asking as simple example, but if you know the solution for this problem, please let the beginner know.

Comment: I;m asking you to explain how this is a programming question ss deinfedin the [help] guideines. It isn't in it's curretnt fom.

Comment: if your files have passed thru Windows, then use `dos2unix file1 file2` tp remove `^M` chars. Good luck.

Comment: oh,, sorry for asking unrelated questions, i did not known there was help center for kind of this question.

Comment: Thank you shellter for your answer.

Comment: It's actually a very good minimally complete example, just the way it's phrased is 'how do I solve this problem I got when using tool x'? I can see @KenWhite's case, but I think a minor tweak is all you need to have this question not be problematic.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @icedwater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your data must be having spaces at each line.

Merging with `,` as delimiter will explain everything.

```
paste -d, file1 file2 > file3

cat file3

1

    ,5

2

    ,6

3

    ,7

4

    ,8
```

to trim these spaces

### With sed:

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' file3 > final.txt
```

### With perl:

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
perl -pne 's/\s+/,/g' < file3 > final.txt
```

Shelter made a [good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192405/why-there-are-hard-returns-when-i-merge-two-files-using-paste-process/36192615#comment60019747_36192405). If you have created file in windows & copied to unix, then it might be having ^M characters. You can see those details using

```
cat -v file1
```

You can replace ^M characters using

```
tr -d '\r' < file3 > final.txt
```

or

```
dos2unix file3 final.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/^M//g' <file3 >final.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness answers, there must be ^M characters in my data.

Comment: @JChoi, is your issue resolved ?

Comment: I am checking the final file. because it has many columns and rows, it might take some times, but i expect the problem will be resolved. Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to `head -50` each file to just test the first 50 rows quickly, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Raju problem is clearly resolved with your kindness help, Thank you very much!